# Google Pay + Sberbank integration error 10

Tags: google-pay

I have made integration by google pay tutorial. Everything is fine, but after i sent payment signature from google pay api response to Sberbank gateway i've got error response about signature verifying problem. What is can be a reason of this error?

```
  function onGooglePaymentButtonClicked() {
    getGooglePaymentsClient().loadPaymentData({
        apiVersion: 2,
        apiVersionMinor: 0,
        allowedPaymentMethods: [
          {
            type: 'CARD',
            parameters: {
              allowedAuthMethods: allowedAuthMethods,
              allowedCardNetworks: allowedCardNetworks
            },
            tokenizationSpecification: tokenizationSpecification
          }
        ],
        transactionInfo: {
          totalPriceStatus: 'FINAL',
          totalPrice: '1',
          currencyCode: 'RUB',
          countryCode: 'RU'
        }
      })
      .then(function(paymentData) {
        processPayment(paymentData);
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
      });
  }
```

Comment: It's hard to say without more context. Are you able to include a reproduction? Something like JSFiddle, StackBlitz or other would be helpful.

Comment: @Soc JSFiddle here [link](https://jsfiddle.net/DavidOstwold/ra7kx8hu/) thanks for helping. After a successful request to Google Pay api, I just send responded signature to the bank gateway api. The bank support service tells me that there is a problem with generating the payment signature in the Google Pay script

Comment: The integration looks good. A couple of suggestions: ensure that the `gatewayMerchantId` you supply is your actual Sberbank merchant identifier, before calling bank API, base64 encode the payment token ([A token received from Google Pay and encoded in Base64.](https://securepayments.sberbank.ru/wiki/doku.php/integration:api:rest:requests:payment_googlepay))